# caching issues in MySQL response with MySQLdb in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, connection, commit

I use MySQL with MySQLdb module in Python, in Django.

I'm running in autocommit mode in this case (and Django's transaction.is_managed() actually returns False).

I have several processes interacting with the database.

One process fetches all Task models with Task.objects.all()

Then another process adds a Task model (I can see it in a database management application).

If I call Task.objects.all() on the first process, I don't see anything. But if I call connection._commit() and then Task.objects.all(), I see the new Task.

My question is: Is there any caching involved at connection level? And is it a normal behaviour (it does not seems to me)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This certainly seems autocommit/table locking - related.

If mysqldb implements the dbapi2 spec it will probably have a connection running as one single continuous transaction. When you say: `'running in autocommit mode'`: do you mean MySQL itself or the mysqldb module? Or Django?

*Not intermittently commiting perfectly explains the behaviour you are getting:*

**i)** a connection implemented as one single transaction in mysqldb (by default, probably)

**ii)** not opening/closing connections only when needed but (re)using one (or more) persistent database connections (my guess, could be Django-architecture-inherited).

**ii)** your selects ('reads') cause a 'simple read lock' on a table (which means other connections can still 'read' this table but connections wanting to 'write data' can't (immediately) because this lock prevents them from getting an 'exclusive lock' (needed 'for writing') on this table. The writing is thus postponed indefinitely (until it can get a (short) exclusive lock on the table for writing - when you close the connection or manually commit).

I'd do the following in your case:

- find out which table locks are on your database during the scenario above
- [read about Django and transactions here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/). A quick skim suggests using standard Django functionality implicitely causes commits. This means sending handcrafted SQL maybe won't (insert, update...).

Comment: Thanks. For the autocommit mode, I mean it from the Django point of view : I have specifically configured Django to autocommit. It could be a bug in Django but I'm quite sure it isn't because it would have other implications. I'll try to use mysqldb directly to see what's going on.

Comment: For i) I'll have to test or find documentation. For ii) I'm using different processes (with management commands), so connection pooling seems impossible. For iii) the writing are done in my case (the process that writes data exits and I can see the data), so it doesn't look like lock related issues.

Comment: I fixed the problem. My understanding of Django transaction management was sort of wrong (but the doc is unclear) : the transaction management doesn't impact what is going on in the db for autocommit or transactionnal mode. It is just a wrapper to run request/response cycles within transactions or not. Django's autocommit isn't an actual autocommit in the db.